# polychoric correlation with items that have different factual max.values but same possible max.values

Tags: r, correlation, psych

I am currently trying to calculate polychoric correlations for my survey-data in R. The data includes 35 variables (items) from my survey. In the survey for all of the items it was possible to answer in categories from 1 to 7. For 10 variables (out of 35) extreme answers like 1 or 7 were not given by the participants (only 2-6) so the max.value of these variables differ from other variables. Yet the possible answer categories are exactly the same.

All of the r functions I found so far (POLYCHORIC_R, mixedCor, hetcor) that calculate polychoric correlation seem to have a problem with that.

Do you have any idea how I can still calculate polychoric correlations in r?